# Existence of solution to linear congruence

Tags: modular-arithmetic, inverse

Given that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime positive integers, and that $a$ is relatively prime to all the following primes: $p_1,p_2,...,p_n$  then the following congruence:$${a+bx}\equiv 1\pmod{ p_1\cdot p_2\cdot p_3 \cdot...\cdot p_n}$$
Has solution in x, why can we claim this?

Comment: Something may be wrong. Is it $b$ that is coprime to all $p_i$?  Is the modulus their *product*?

Comment: @BillDubuque Oh, you're right, messed up the LaTeX, the modulus it's their product, I'll fix it immediately!

Comment: This question is missing context or other details: Please provide additional context, which ideally explains why the question is relevant to you and our community. Some forms of context include: background and motivation, relevant definitions, source, possible strategies, your current progress, why the question is interesting or important, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is solvable $\iff \gcd(n,b)\mid 1\!-\!a,\,$ where $n = \prod p_i.\,$ Indeed

$\qquad\qquad \begin{align} 
\!\bmod n\!:\ \exists x\!:\ bx\equiv&\, 1\!-\!a\\[.3em] 
\iff \exists x,y\!:\ ny+bx =&\, 1\!-\!a\\[.3em] 
\iff \gcd(n,\,b)\,\ \mid\ &\ 1\!-\!a\ \ {\rm by\ Bezout}\end{align}$